# How to disable mailto: when clicking an Email like filename?

Tags: c#, pdf

Consider this simple block of code that reproduces a simple text with a web hyperlink to a file located in the user's file-system.

```
Document doc = new Document();
Page page1 = doc.Pages.Add();
TextFragment textFragment = new TextFragment();            
TextSegment textSegment = new TextSegment("foo@boo.net");
textSegment.Hyperlink = new Aspose.Pdf.WebHyperlink("Images/foo@boo.net");
textFragment.Segments.Add(textSegment);
page1.Paragraphs.Add(textFragment);
doc.Save(dataDir);
```

The file **name** is `foo@boo.net` and therefor the PDF recognizes it as an Email and automatically adds a `mailto:` prefix, so instead of opening the file (with some default program) its being opened with Outlook.

This question is followed by my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71111693/6844481) regarding this issue, after many attempts like trying using the `new Aspose.Pdf.FileHyperlink("Images/foo@boo.net");` but then it does not open any of the files whatever its name is.

**Is it possible to add a `TextSegment` with a valid mail text so the PDF reader won't add the `mailto:` prefix?**

For example (tested in Chrome):
[image]

Comment: maybe using the `file:/` protocol in your link works?

Comment: Hi @FranzGleichmann Nope, that does not help because the problem is with `TextSegment("foo@boo.net");` regardless of what inside the HyperLink

Comment: What PDF readers have you tested in? I'm skeptical that Acrobat or Chrome would _automatically_ add `mailto:` by themselves...

Comment: you could try adding a zero-width-whitespace in the text to break the address-recognition

Comment: I've tested in Chrome (updated my question)

Comment: It definitely seems worth considering to not go against the grain of things and just not use file names like these. For example, by replacing the `@` with `_` or `[at]`. This sort of "helpful" detection can be expected in more places, after all (like inside a mail itself).

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert I liked your comment, could you please explain what do you mean by "like inside a mail itself"?

Comment: What I meant is that if you mailed information like "please see the file foo@bar.net", the mail client is very likely to turn that into a clickable mailto: link itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by escaping the text with `zero-width-whitespace` ([definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)) like:

```
internal static string SafeEscapeMailtoPrefix(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return value;
    return value.Replace("@", "\u200B@");
}
```

So the TextSegment will be like:

```
TextSegment textSegment = newTextSegment("foo@boo.net".SafeEscapeMailtoPrefix());
```

Comment: It is nice to know that your issue has been sorted out. Please note that we recommend posting such inquiries in the official support forum of Aspose.PDF i.e. https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf. Please post such questions in the suggested forum and we will assist you there accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: It is good you asked (and answered) this question here as the solution is not Aspose specific but applies analogously to arbitrary PDF libraries. +1